# How to add BiFunction on a MAP properly

Tags: java, lambda, functional-interface

```
private static final Map<String, BiFunction<String, Player, Player>> SELF_FUNCTION = Map.of
(
    "pAtk", BiFunction<Integer, Player, Player> pAtk = (k, v) -> k.getPAtk(v),
    "mAtk", BiFunction<Integer, Player, Player> mAtk = (k, v) -> k.getMAtk(v),
);
```

I can't manage to make this code to be working. I want to do a for entry and get the Key and calculate the stat is given by BiFunction but i can't make it work.

Comment: You can't write a variable definition as part of the argument. Look at the `String` argument you're providing. Here you're not writing `String s = "pAtk"` there, right? Simply `(k, v) -> k.getPAtk(v)` is enough

Comment: This makes no sense at all. In the first line, you declare the first bifunction param as String, then inside the block zou declare it as Integer. Then inside the lambdas (where that String or Integer is called k), you are calling `k.getPAtk` which is certainly neither a method of String or Integer, but probably or `Player` (we can only guess).

Comment: Thank you very much i made it worked by "pAtk", L2Character::getPAtk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [`BiFunction<T, U, R>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiFunction.html) definition `T` is the type of the first argument, `U` is the type of the second argument, `R` is the return type.

Thus, providing that class `Player` contains methods `Player getPAtk(String v)` and `Player getMAtk(String v)`, the map of `BiFunction<Player, String, Player>` can be created as:

```java
private static final Map<String, BiFunction<Player, String, Player>> SELF_FUNCTION = Map.of (
        "pAtk", (player, value) -> player.getPAtk(value), // or Player::getPAtk
        "mAtk", (player, value) -> player.getMAtk(value) // or Player::getMAtk
);
```

or switch the arguments in the lambda to match `BiFunction` definition:

```java
private static final Map<String, BiFunction<String, Player, Player>> SELF_FUNCTION = Map.of (
        "pAtk", (value, player) -> player.getPAtk(value),
        "mAtk", (value, player) -> player.getMAtk(value)
);
```